# How to wrap each return result with an XML node using Xquery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex, flwor

Perhaps its possible to add an additional for loop around each return, and so wrap the result with a node?

Modifying a w3 schools sample [query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_add.asp):

```
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ basex bookstore.category.name.xq 
<xml>
  <category>cooking</category>
  <title>Everyday Italian</title>
  <category>children</category>
  <title>Harry Potter</title>
  <category>web</category>
  <title>Learning XML</title>
  <category>web</category>
  <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
</xml>nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ cat bookstore.category.name.xq 

xquery version "3.1";


<xml>
{
for $x in db:open("bookstore")/bookstore/book
order by $x/title
return (<category>{data($x/@category)}</category>,<title>{data($x/title)}</title>)
}
</xml>
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$
```

how can I wrap each result with a book element?

The `xml` sample data:

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

from the w3schools site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<xml>
{
for $x in db:open("bookstore")/bookstore/book
let $category := data($x/@category)
return (
for $book in $x  
  let $title := data($book/title)
  return(
<book>
<category>{$category}</category><title>{$title}</title>)
</book>)
)
}
</xml>
```

Output:

```
<xml>
  <book>
    <category>cooking</category>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>)
</book>
  <book>
    <category>children</category>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>)
</book>
  <book>
    <category>web</category>
    <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>)
</book>
  <book>
    <category>web</category>
    <title>Learning XML</title>)
</book>
</xml>
```

Comment: why is `$x` looped in the inner loop?  I would think another index would be required.  (as when iterating through a matrix with i,j notation.  perhaps that doesn't apply at all.)

Comment: @NicholasSaunders If I understand the question correctly, we need to go through `$x` to extract the attribute value of the `category` attribute of `$x`. Then we need to go down to `$x`'s child  `<title>` to extract its text value; so we have to use it twice.